# CSS making :before element inherit size (491th time)

Tags: html, css

Hey this question has been asked at least thrice a year but none of what I try works. [JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/3pqhjyk4/)

I want to have a transparent background box so I went for `:before` which works except that I need to input the height statically. The webpage scrolls down multiple pages and every browser/screen size renders that differently so I'd like to find a way to automatically make the :before element inherit the height of what div the :before "targeted" (sorry for that bad language but I don't know anything about web dev).

I could type more but the 20-line JSFiddle is pretty self-explanatory, putting `position: relative` like people advised and deleting the height/width attributes makes the :before disappear completely and I have no clue what to do else.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ff0000;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background: #dccbff;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#content {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#content:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  /* people say I should put
                         relative here but then
                         the whole box disappears */
  height: 43px;
  width: 100%;
  /* removing height and width also makes the box
    disappear. I'd love to use something like "auto"
    or "100%" but the page is scrollable so I need
    the :before element to be resized dynamically */
  opacity: .4;
  z-index: -1;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  not readable
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="content">
    so I want this to be on a darker background that dynamically changes its size with the size of "content"
    <br>but as you see it only does it until here
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The 20-line JSFiddle is self-explanatory... when it works. Given that JSFiddle is *notorious* for its frequent downtimes, I suggest just putting the 20 lines of code here to make everyone's lives easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to give your outer box a `position`, be it `absolute` or `relative` (or `fixed`). Now your `:before`, being considered a child of that element, will work just like any other nested element and you can make it stretch. Heres your code amended:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #ff0000;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background: #dccbff;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#content {
    /* Added this line */
    position: relative;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#content:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    /* Made the height 100% */
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;  
    opacity: .4; 
    z-index: -1; 
    background: #000;
}

/* Cheekily added this as well. */
#content span { text-decoration: line-through; }
```

```html
<div id="main">
    Not readable <br/> <br/>
    <div id="content">
        So I want this to be on a darker background that dynamically changes its size with the size of "content" <br /> but as you see it <span>only does it until here</span> now does it entirely.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh great! Thanks a lot for explanation, that worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Basically you want something like this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ff0000;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background: #dccbff;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.content {
  color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.content:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: .4;
  z-index: -1;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="content">so I want this to be on a darker background that dynamically changes its size with the size of "content"
  </div>
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil unde hic aut mollitia molestias provident, velit ipsam itaque, earum dolorum expedita magnam, architecto accusamus neque asperiores aliquam atque natus doloribus officia dolores. Velit
    nam dignissimos aut nobis earum quasi dolores dolorum, quidem veniam harum ipsam mollitia, assumenda, cupiditate consectetur. Blanditiis!
  </div>
</div>
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3pqhjyk4/3/)

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't solve the "scrollable" problem. In the comment I said "I'd love to use something like "auto"
    or "100%" but the page is scrollable so I need
    the :before element to be resized dynamically" and at least on Safari and Chrome the box ends where the display ends. After scrolling the box is cropped.

Comment: The psuedo element is sized dynamically to the parent element. I'm not sure what effect you are after...it's not clear.

Comment: @user2875404 The outer element isn't absolute so this does not affect scrolling in any way. Your outer box is still in the flow.

Comment: Sorry but I haven't seen that you added "position: relative;" in the .content, I thought your change is only suggesting putting 100% at both height and width. However, yes this works, thanks a lot.